# If the person has this emoji in their name, they should take this role. (From emojis written to the database)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is the code:

```
     let args1 = args[0]
     await db.set("write_", args1)
```

"**.write** " when I use the code like.I am getting such a result:

```
  "write_": ""
```

"**.write** " But when I use it like this, this is the result:

```
  "write_": ""
```

My problem here is that the first value I entered is deleted, a new value is entered.

But when I do the code:

```
     let args1 = args[0]
     await db.push("write_", args1)
```

This is the result:

```
  "write_": [
"",
""
]
```

I want to print it this way:

```
  "write_": "",
  "write_": ""
```

Is something like this possible ?
The reason I want to do

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

     let newMember = member.user.tag
     let role = member.guild.roles.cache.get("707628035498836069");

     if(newMember.includes(db.fetch("yasaklıtag_"))) {
     member.roles.add(role)
}
});
```

If there is one of the emojis in the database in the name of the person entering the server, it gives that person the "role" role.

So briefly, if someone has one of these emojis in their name.I want her to take the role of "role".

Comment: "I want to print it this way:":

Share how you are currently printnt it.

Comment: "write_": [
"",
""
]

Comment: I meant. You want to have it print one way, but it's printed the other way. However, you didn't show what you do to print it currently. Share the code that prints it.

Comment: ` let args1 = args[0]
     await db.push("write_", args1)` This turns out when I run this code : `"write_": ["", ""]` But this is how I want to print : ` "write_": "",
  "write_": "" ` I don't know what to do to print this way.